# What's the relation between free margin and drawdown? (and leverage)

Tags: trading, margin

I'm trying to understand whether different leverages can affect the drawdown in forex/CFD trading.

1. I have noticed that given the same lot size, the bigger the account leverage, then the bigger is the free margin when you open a position. Is this correct?
2. Assuming the above is correct, will a higher free-margin result in lower drawdown when a position goes against you? To put it in other words: Should I use the highest leverage the broker offers to keep drawdown as low as possible?

* I'm assuming the same lot size is used. Only want to spot the differences/relation between `leverage`, `free-margin` and `drawdown` when a position goes against you.

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure I can answer the question but highly-leveraged positions will go nasty on you much faster than unleveraged positions when things go south. This will affect drawdown.

Comment: Hi @ApplePie, are you sure on this? Isn't the volume (aka lot size) of the position what potentially can make the position to go nasty? As I'm understanding, high leverage allows you to open big positions, but it does not force you from doing so. Maybe I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The amount of leverage that is used is the correct fundamental. Add the free margin to the required margin and divide by the position size. Then take the reciprocal to get the x-times of leverage.

If account-one has $4000 with $2000 required to hold a $100000 position then the overall leverage is $4000 / $100000 with the reciprocal determining 25 times leverage.

If account-two has $4000 with $1000 required to hold a $100000 position then the overall leverage is the same as account-one
.

Comment: Hi @s-pring, thanks for your answer. I'm not sure I'm understanding your answer. Regarding my two questions above, could you tell if I'm right or wrong? What I'm trying to figure out is whether the account leverage has impact on the drawdown for same position size. For example, some brokers let you use 1:30, 1:100 or 1:500 for same account type. Thanks :)

Comment: The amount of drawdown is relative to the overall leverage that is used and not to the maximum leverage that is allowed. Maybe the subject is looking for maintenance margin ? Personally, I've never considered maintenance margin of forex but just stay some percentage off maximum allowed leverage. I assume maximum allowed margin and maintenance margin to be the same amount.

Comment: For simple example, $2000 holds a $100000 position. The position peak here is $100000. The position drawsdown to $98000 and that's a margin call since remaining margin is only $1800. The margin decreases 10% as 200 / 2000. Well, add $200 to the beginning margin of $2000 for $2200. Now when the position drawsdown to $98000 the margin decreases from $2200 to $2000 and there is no margin call. Here the margin decreases 9.09% as 200 / 2200.